# Select primary dropdown and force other dropdowns to select the option with the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

When the **Primary dropdown** changes, I want the other dropdown to change accordingly.

But I dont know why **only the 1st Other dropdown is working** while the 2nd fails to change its value accordingly. I
m aware that if I change the name of the 2nd dropdown to the same as the 1st dropdown it will work.

But as they are different fields that are to be saved in the db, so the names have to be different.

Any solution would be appreciated. Many thanks.

```js
function setDropDown() {
  var index_name =
    document.getElementsByName('ForceSelection')[0].selectedIndex;
  var others = document.getElementsByName('Qualifications');
  for (i = 0; i < others.length; i++)
    others[i].selectedIndex = index_name;

  var others2 = document.getElementsByName('Qualifications2');
  for (i = 0; i < others2.length; i++)
    others2[i].selectedIndex = index_name2;
}
```

```html
Primary dropdown<select name="ForceSelection" id="ForceSelection" onChange="javascript:return setDropDown();">
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
<option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select> other dropdown
<select id="Qualifications" name="Qualifications">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select> other dropdown2
<select id="Qualifications2" name="Qualifications2">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you run the snippet? `Uncaught ReferenceError: others2 is not defined`. You defined the variable as `others1`, then tried to access `others2`

Comment: have changed that, but still fails to work,any idea?

Comment: Did you run the snippet? `Uncaught ReferenceError: index_name2 is not defined`. You haven't defined `index_name2`.

Comment: Oh.that's right, it works now, thanks mate, still very new to this

Comment: Your best tool is the console. Stack snippets actually has a console built in, so if you click "Run code snippet" on your post, you will be able to see any errors that come up. You can also use the developer console built into most modern browsers.

Comment: got it, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css class to your secondary drop downs and use `document.querySelectorAll` to get them all at once.

Then you can use a single loop to update their `selectedIndex`.

```js
function setDropDown() {
  var index_name =
    document.getElementsByName('ForceSelection')[0].selectedIndex;
  var others = document.querySelectorAll('.secondary');
  for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i++) {
    others[i].selectedIndex = index_name;
  }

}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div><b>Primary dropdown:</b>
  <select name="ForceSelection" id="ForceSelection" onChange="javascript:return setDropDown();">
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
<option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <b>Other dropdown 1</b>:
  <select class='secondary' id="Qualifications" name="Qualifications">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select></div>
<div> <b>Other dropdown 1</b>:
  <select class='secondary' id="Qualifications2" name="Qualifications2">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out i haven't defined sth in my code, thanks for pointing that out  @Tiny Giant

```js
function setDropDown() {
  var index_name =
    document.getElementsByName('ForceSelection')[0].selectedIndex;
    
    var index_name2 =
    document.getElementsByName('ForceSelection')[0].selectedIndex;
    
  var others = document.getElementsByName('Qualifications');
  for (i = 0; i < others.length; i++)
    others[i].selectedIndex = index_name;

  var others2 = document.getElementsByName('Qualifications2');
  for (j = 0; j < others2.length; j++)
    others2[j].selectedIndex = index_name2;
}
```

```html
Primary dropdown<select name="ForceSelection" id="ForceSelection" onChange="javascript:return setDropDown();">
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
<option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select> other dropdown
<select id="Qualifications" name="Qualifications">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select> other dropdown2
<select id="Qualifications2" name="Qualifications2">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't need 2 variables for the same value, you can simply do `others2[j].selectedIndex = index_name`